# Lightest way to store a numpy array

Tags: python

I am trying to store a large Numpy array into a file which I will then read on a google collab notebook to (GPU needed from collab for some machine learning).

I have first saved the files into a text file but each of the three files has a size of about 300.000 kb. Opening these files on collab takes about 2 hours...

Is there any other type of file that you would recommend for this? Should I try using compression? 
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compress numpy arrays efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400652/compress-numpy-arrays-efficiently)

Comment: Don't use a text file, use `np.save` to save it in binary format