# Best method for storing a large array of large integers in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, storage

I have a large `numpy` array (188,995 values to be exact) containing 18-digit integers. Here would be the first 5:

```
array([873205635515447425, 872488459744513265, 872556415745513809,
       872430459826834345, 867251246913838889])
```

The array's dtype is `dtype('int64')`. I'm currently storing this array in a `.npy` file that's 1.5mb in size.

I'll be storing a couple of these arrays every day, and I want to be conscious of storage. If it helps, the integers are always 18-digits long. They don't have any discernible pattern, so dividing them down won't work.

I was able to decrease the file size to 1.4mb by gzip compressing and storing as a `.npy.gz` file, but that's the lowest it'll go.

**Is there a way to compress the array down further?**

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/40542980/2640045.

Comment: yep saw that answer and that's exactly how I got down to 1.4mb. was wondering whether I was missing any other methods

Comment: The `npy` file contains a byte image of that array, that is 8 bytes per number, same as the in memory.  Your numbers are close to the upper limit of what a `int64` can store (without overflow).  There isn't much room for compression without loss of precision.  Images and text have a lot of "redundancy" that can be compressed out, your data does not.

Comment: thanks @hpaulj you're right. for any future readers, I found that converting the array and saving as a parquet file with brotli compression gave me the lowest file size, 1.3mb

Comment: Can you provide more of these values? If possible a whole chunk.